# What does "array" here mean?

Tags: meaning

> We can't see anything until you get the camera **array** fixed.

*from vi.glosbe.com*

I looked up the word in the dictionary and its definition is:

> a large group of things or people, esp. when shown or positioned in an
>   attractive way

*From the Cambridge dictionary.*

But it doesn't seem to fit here in the context.

Comment: It fits, a large group of cameras.

Comment: Perhaps, several cameras are used to form the image.

Comment: Okay, thank you!

Comment: What is the source of the quote please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A camera array is a group of cameras, perhaps arranged in a grid or a line, used (for example) to capture images in high resolution or at high speed. For example, the "bullet time" effect used in *The Matrix* movies, used a camera array.

In the context of the quote, it seems likely that several cameras are being used to make an image.

Comment: Thank you! I got it now